# Validation errors not defined. Cant find fix

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I keep receiving errors that my functions for validation are not defined and I might just be stupid but I cant find the issue. Could anyone try and see what is wrong with my code. As far as I can see there are no spelling mistakes anywhere in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
    .errorMsg {
        color:red;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .required {
        color:red;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h1 class="mt-3">Contact Us</h1>
            <p>
                Complete the form below to send us a message.
            </p>
            <div id="respMsgAlert" class="alert alert-danger visually-hidden" role="alert">
                <div id="respMsgText"></div>
            </div>
            <form name="formOne" action="https://placeholder.com/placeholder.php" method="get">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="firstName" class="form-label"><span class="required">*</span> First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" onfocus="clearFirstNameValidation()" onblur="validateFirstName()">
                    <div id="firstNameValidation" class="errorMsg"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="lastName" class="form-label"><span class="required">*</span> Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" onfocus="clearLastNameValidation()" onblur="validateLastName()">
                    <div id="lastNameValidation" class="errorMsg"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="emailAddress" class="form-label"><span class="required">*</span> Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" onfocus="clearEmailAddressValidation()" onblur="validateEmailAddress()">
                    <div id="emailAddressValidation" class="errorMsg"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="phoneNumber" class="form-label"><span class="required">*</span> Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" onfocus="clearPhoneNumberValidation()" onblur="validatePhoneNumber()">
                    <div id="phoneNumberValidation" class="errorMsg"></div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <span class="required">*</span> denotes a value is required to proceed.
        </div>
        <div id="" class="col-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
   const NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 20;
const EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH = 50;
const PHONE_MAX_LENGTH = 15;
let pageIsValid = false;

/**
 * Submit form if valid
 */
function submitForm() {
  if (pageIsValid) {
    // clear alert info and hide
    document.getElementById('respMsgText').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('respMsgAlert').classList.add('visually-hidden');
    // submit the form info
    document.formOne.submit();
  } else {
    // set alert text and show
    document.getElementById('respMsgText').innerHTML = 'Form is not valid. Please correct errors before submitting.';
    document.getElementById('respMsgAlert').classList.remove('visually-hidden');
  }
}

/**
 * Clear validation for name
 */
function clearFirstNameValidation() {
  document.getElementById('firstNameValidation').innerHTML = '';
}


/**
 * Validate the name provided
 */
function validateFirstName() {
  let firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  if (firstName.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById('firstNameValidation').innerHTML = 'First Name is required!';
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else if (firstName.length > NAME_MAX_LENGTH) {
    document.getElementById('firstNameValidation').innerHTML = `First Name cannot exceed ${NAME_MAX_LENGTH} characters!`;
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else {
    pageIsValid = true;
  }
}
/**
 * Clear validation for last name
 */
function clearLastNameValidation() {
  document.getElementById('lastNameValidation').innerHTML = '';
}

/**
 * Validate the last name provided
 */
function validateLastName() {
  let lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  if (lastName.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById('lastNameValidation').innerHTML = 'Last name is required!';
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else if (lastName.length > NAME_MAX_LENGTH) {
    document.getElementById('lastNameValidation').innerHTML = `Last name cannot exceed ${NAME_MAX_LENGTH} characters!`;
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else {
    pageIsValid = true;
  }
}

/**
 * Clear validation for email
 */
function clearEmailAddressValidation() {
  document.getElementById('emailAddressValidation').innerHTML = '';
}

/**
 * Validate the email provided
 */
function validateEmailAddress() {
  let emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailAddress').value;
  const emailRegex = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
  if (emailAddress.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById('emailAddressValidation').innerHTML = 'Email Address is required!';
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else if (emailAddress.length > EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH) {
    document.getElementById('emailAddressValidation').innerHTML = `Email Address cannot exceed ${EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH} characters!`;
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else if (!emailRegex.test(emailAddress)) {
    document.getElementById('emailAddressValidation').innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email address!';
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else {
    pageIsValid = true;
  }
}

/**
 * Clear validation for phone number
 */
function clearPhoneNumberValidation() {
  document.getElementById('phoneNumberValidation').innerHTML = '';
}

/**
 * Validate the phone number provided
 */
function validatePhoneNumber() {
  let phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
  const phoneRegex = /^\d{10}$/;
  if (phoneNumber.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById('phoneNumberValidation').innerHTML = 'Phone Number is required!';
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else if (phoneNumber.length > PHONE_MAX_LENGTH) {
    document.getElementById('phoneNumberValidation').innerHTML = `Phone Number cannot exceed ${PHONE_MAX_LENGTH} digits!`;
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else if (!phoneRegex.test(phoneNumber)) {
    document.getElementById('phoneNumberValidation').innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid phone number (10 digits only)!';
    pageIsValid = false;
  } else {
    pageIsValid = true;
  }
```

Tried changing around validation names and nothing worked. Continued to get the same errors

Comment: You may not have spelling errors, but you do have errors in your code. Please put it through a validator (eg the one supplied by W3C). Problems I have spotted: style element between the head and body elements, no end tag for the script tag, no end tag for the body tag, no end tag for the html tag. If you cure these then the functions are defined.

Comment: cant believe i didnt notice those missing end tags, fixed everything and it all works now, thanks!